# Using factors to write new columns in R

Tags: r

I have a table with 8 variables, one of them is a factor with 3 levels. I want to write something in a new column based on which of the the levels but can't figure it out.

```
if(Nitro[Nitro$Result == "push", ]){
    Nitro$Profit <- 0
}
```

Comment: In future use `dput` of your data (or a sample) so people can reproduce it

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using data frames, this should work.

```
 Nitro$Profit[Nitro$Result == "push"] <- 0
```

If you are using data table, try:

```
Nitro[Result == "push", Profit := 0]
```

Comment: It worked very well for the 0, however when I try to add one of the variables (negative)I get the error:
"number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

This is the code i try 

       `Nitro$Profit[Nitro$Result == "lose"] <- - Nitro$Innsats`

Comment: `require(data.table)`; `Nitro <- data.table(Nitro)` ; `Nitro[Result == "lose", Profit := Innsats]`

Comment: Perfect, you guys are the best!!